# Activity browser user interface: bw2data.backends.peewee.schema.ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist

Tags: brightway

I was working with bw2 on a jupiter notebook. I was successfully linking inventories in excel files with the activity browser.

Today, I cannot open the activity browser user interface anymore & I get this message.

bw2data.backends.peewee.schema.ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist: <Model: ActivityDataset> instance matching query does not exist:
SQL: SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."data", "t1"."code", "t1"."database", "t1"."location", "t1"."name", "t1"."product", "t1"."type" FROM "activitydataset" AS "t1" WHERE (("t1"."database" = ?) AND ("t1"."code" = ?)) ORDER BY Random() LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

I installed the newest update activitybrowser 2.4 but still I get the same message.

Comment: Hi Mohammad-

The key to figuring this out comes from the error name: `ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist`. This means that at some point the activity browser is looking for a certain activity, but that activity is not found. We know it is looking for a specific activity because of the SQL fragment `("t1"."database" = ?) AND ("t1"."code" = ?)`.

Can you describe exactly what you are doing to produce this error message?

Comment: Hi Chris,

I was importing the ecoinvent database when the system ran out of memory & crashed.

Comment: https://github.com/LCA-ActivityBrowser/activity-browser/issues/611